# Java for loop i++ as a string

Tags: java, for-loop

Let's say we have a for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ...
}
```

What format is the `i++` in?

I have a `String increment = "i++"` which tells me how much to increment `i` by.
But when I just directly try and put the increment string as an incrementor it doesn't work. I tried the below but it doesn't work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; increment) {
    ...
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: A string is not a statement, it's an object / variable. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: This tutorial might helps to understand how for-loop works; https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_for_loop.htm. i++ is same as i=i+1 but i is defined as an integer. Having "i++" inside quotes is a string and Java doesn't care what's inside that string. It is just a set of characters to Java.

Comment: your question is unclear. what exactly is `increment`?

Comment: Moreover if you're looking for a way to have a "dynamic" incrementer, you could use an `IntUnaryOperator`: `IntUnaryOperator inc = w -> w++;`, `inc.apply(i)`

Answer (score 0):

The increment need to be an direct attribution,
you can't use a String to define this, is impossible

One solution to change dynamically how much will be the increment, it's using a variable

```
int j=1;

for(int i=0;i<10;i+=j)
```

the += operator it's used for the increment, for example:

```
int x = 0;
x += 1; //x is 1
x += 3; //x is 4
x += 2; //x is 6
x++; //x is 7
```

But in the most cases you don't need to use this in a for loop, what you need to do?

Hugs

Answer (score 0):

So for this, you cannot use a string as a expression. 
There will be quite a few ways to map a String to expression.

One of the ways is you can use switch case:

```
String increment = "i++";
int i = 0;
while(i < 10)
{ 
  //your logic here
  switch (increment){
    case "i++": 
      i++;
      break;
    case "i=i+2": 
      i = i + 2;
      break;
  }
}
```

You can also use Regex or parse the String to convert to int

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the increment string to an int then use that as your increment in your loop:

```
String increment = "i+2"; // Will also work for "i++" or "i+n" (n = a number)
String num = increment.replaceAll("i\\+*", "");
int incValue = 1;
if(!num.isEmpty())
    incValue = Integer.parseInt(num);

for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i+=incValue)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get increment count in a string if you want to do increment dynamically, instead of whole increment statement. Here is an example:

```
String inc = "2";
String max = "10";
for(int i = 0; i < Integer.valueOf(max); i=i+Integer.valueOf(inc)) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`i++` is just code : it's not a string as you thought.

Here's an analogy to demonstrate your assumption:

```
String someString =
    "public static void doStuff()
    {
        System.out.println("this is working");
    }";
```

Now if you refer to the String `someString` in a separate method, do you think that the doStuff() method will be called? Of course not, because String is just text that the interpreter doesn't go through. The interpreter can only go through executable code, which includes the `i++` in question.